# How can I search for the last email received from a domain in Google Sheets?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have a list of people who I have contacted in the past, and I want to pull the last email that they sent to me in google sheets.

I found this: https://dilipkashyap15.medium.com/how-to-fetch-gmail-data-in-google-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script-b9c63b260f8f

Which works for me to get emails from the inbox.

I modified the code to

```
function findLastEmail(text){
var threads = GmailApp.search('from:"'&text&'"');
var messages = threads[threads.length - 1].getMessages();
var msgCount = threads[threads.length - 1].getMessageCount();
message = messages[messages.length - 1];
extractDetails(message,msgCount)
}
```

However, when I try to run this using a custom function (typing `=findLastEmail("abc@gmail.com")`), I get the following error -

> Exception: The script does not have permission to perform that action. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify || https://mail.google.com/)
> at findLastEmail(Code:25:24)

However, I do not receive any error if I manually change the function to

```
function findLastEmail(text){
var threads = GmailApp.search('from:"abc@gmail.com"');
var messages = threads[threads.length - 1].getMessages();
var msgCount = threads[threads.length - 1].getMessageCount();
message = messages[messages.length - 1];
extractDetails(message,msgCount)
}
```

and run from the Apps Scripts

Comment: In your situation, how did you run your script?

Comment: I ran using the run function in the apps script (however, since I have a list of emails in my spreadsheet, ideally, I'd like to run using a custom function e.g. =findLastEmail(A2))

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `I ran using the run function in the apps script`, in your situation, when you run your script with the script editor, an error like `Exception: The script does not have permission to perform that action. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify || https://mail.google.com/) at findLastEmail(Code:25:24)` occurs. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, that happens when I run it like a custom function (i.e. in the spreadsheet)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `No, that happens when I run it like a custom function (i.e. in the spreadsheet)`, I understood that your `I ran using the run function in the apps script` is to run the script as a custom function. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. From your error message and showing script, I'm worried that `GmailApp.search` cannot be used with the custom function. So, how about confirming the official document about this? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_services

Answer (score 0):

On Google Sheets extended by Google Apps Scripts, **custom functions** have limitations that JavaScript functions run from the Google Apps Script editor haven't. One of those limitations is that they can't call services that require authorization, like GmailApp. For details, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
function findLastEmail(domain) {
  let idA = [];
  const ts = GmailApp.search(`From:${domain}`);
  ts.forEach(t => {
    let ms = t.getMessages();
    ms.forEach(m => {
      idA.push({ id: m.getId(), date: m.getDate() });
    })
  })
  idA.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.date.valueOf() - a.date.valueOf();
  })
  let m = GmailApp.getMessageById(idA[0].id);
  Logger.log('Date: %s,Subject: %s, Message: %s', m.getDate(), m.getSubject(), m.getPlainBody());
}
```